# Laravel url not showing javascript location.hash

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and I am trying to use javascript after an ajax post to get the query parameters with location.hash .
It's returning nothing.
Does it have to do with the way the routes are set up that it's not recognizing after the ?

http://localhost/laravel/oorahaccount/public/account/dashboardmain?code=complete

Answer (score 0):

`location.hash` will return the part of the URL that follows the hash mark `#` (including the hash mark).

You need the querystring, so you should be using `location.search`